# Join a list of tuples with a formatting in an efficient manner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list of tuples

```
a = [(5, 2), (2, 4)]
```

And I need to output the following text

```
(5,2) (2,4)
```

I have tried

```
[",".join(str(i) for i in j) for j in a]
```

And it provides the following list

```
['5,3', '2,4']
```

But haven't found an efficient way of getting the desired output, and it must work for a list of tuples of different sizes.

Comment: `' '.join(map(repr, a))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `str.join` method with a generator expression like the following:

```
' '.join('(%s)' % ','.join(map(str, t)) for t in a)
```

This returns a string with the following content:

```
(5,2) (2,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is get string output then:

1. Convert to a string
2. Strip the brackets

`str(a).strip("[]")`

out:
`'(5,2) (2,4)'`

Comment: This outputs (5, 2) (2, 4) instead of (5,2) (2,4)

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this.

> **join()** method works on a container of strings so we converted tuples to string for using **str()** function.

```
>>> text = " ".join(str(tup).replace(" ", '') for tup in a)
>>> text
'(5,2) (2,4)'
>>>
>>> print(text)
(5,2) (2,4)
>>>
```

In case, if you want omma separated

```
>>> text = ",".join(str(tup).replace(" ", '') for tup in a)
>>> 
>>> text
'(5,2),(2,4)'
>>>
```

> **Suggestion:** Finally, you can wrap the code inside a function `get_list_as_str()` and call it many times whenever you want to get list of tuples as string (A concept of code reusability).

```
>>> def get_list_as_str(a):
...     text = " ".join(str(tup).replace(" ", '') for tup in a)
...     return text
... 
>>> 
>>> a = [(1, 5, 6), (4,7, 8, 9), (4, 7)]
>>> text = get_list_as_str(a)
>>> print(text)
(1,5,6) (4,7,8,9) (4,7)
>>> 
>>> b = [(1,1), (4,7, 8), (3, 3, 2, 9, 10, 5 * 6)]
>>> text = get_list_as_str(b)
>>> print(text)
(1,1) (4,7,8) (3,3,2,9,10,30)
>>>
```

That's it.

Comment: I need to get rid of the space between the numbers of the tuples, so I need another method.

Comment: Got it, check again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the best way to do it, but this definitely helps.

```
a = [(5, 2), (2, 4)]
(str(a)[1:-1]).replace("),",')')
```

Output:

```
'(5, 2) (2, 4)'
```